# How to properly exec a long-running database operation during the launching phase in rocket.rs?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am trying to make a long-running (~1min) function call which queries the database and constructs some data objects for upcoming usage. But it will give me a runtime panic if I create a `postgres::Client` within the launch function.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.'
```

a minimal sample code snippet will be like this:

```
use postgres::{Client, NoTls};
use my_crate::my_libs::fill_data_model_from_db;

#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

#[get("/world")]
fn world() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    let mut client: Client = Client::connect("host=localhost dbname=testdb", NoTls).unwrap();
    // long running db queries for data preparation
    // let d = fill_data_model_from_db(&mut client);
    // will use State to encapsulate `d`
    rocket::build().mount("/hello", routes![world])
}
```

It's a bit strange to me that although the `postgres::Client` is actually a `synchronous PostgreSQL client` as its document says, why the creation of it will cause a nested tokio runtime issue? I already took a look at the [rocket_db_pools](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket_db_pools/index.html), but could not figure out how the db pool would help here. I'm still pretty new to rust and rocket. Any hint or help will be super welcome! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: [docs](https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/index.html): *"This crate is a lightweight wrapper over tokio-postgres. The `postgres::Client` is simply a wrapper around a `tokio_postgres::Client` along side a tokio `Runtime`. The client simply blocks on the futures provided by the async client.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`postgres::Client` is synchronous from the point of view of the caller, but it works by creating a runtime and calling the asynchronous API internally.

In this case the solution is pretty easy: simply make your `rocket` function `async` and use the asynchronous Postgres API:

```
use tokio_postgres::{Client, NoTls};

#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

#[get("/world")]
fn world() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

#[launch]
async fn rocket() -> _ {
    let (client, connection) = tokio_postgres::connect("host=localhost dbname=testdb", NoTls).await.unwrap();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        if let Err(e) = connection.await {
            eprintln!("connection error: {}", e);
        }
    });
    // use `client` to make asynchronous DB requests
    rocket::build().mount("/hello", routes![world])
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! The only necessary further adjustments to the codes to make it work are: 1). to use `tokio_postgres::connect` instead of `Client::connect`; 2). add a `tokio::spawn(async move { if let Err(e) = connection.await { error!("connection error: {}", e); } });`  before using the `client`.